# Is it possible to cross train Kyokushin and Freestyle Wrestling?

Tags: karate, wrestling

I will definitely be training again in Kyokushin Karate again soon. My question is, does anyone recommend cross training it with Freestyle Wrestling aswell?

I am not interested in competing in MMA or even Muay Thai for that matter. I would consider doing Kyokushin matches and Freestyle Wrestling matches but just them on their own. Just want anyone's advice who knows weather that is a good idea or not? Maybe you've done a similar regime and it hasn't worked out or it has been awesome? Either way everyone's response to this post will be listened to and not criticised...

In the end scenario I will be doing Kyokushin, just wanting to decide about Wrestling. Please give some advice?

Regards- Drew 27 from New Zealand.

Comment: This is unclear as we have no idea of what your goals are. You say you are not interested in a few things, what about what you are interested in? In additions, most of the tone of your question prompt discussion which we do not do.

Comment: You don't discuss? What is this forum for then if you don't discuss things?

Comment: We are **not** a forum. We are a question and answer site. Maybe you should take the [tour](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works?

Comment: Sardathrion is right. Here on Martial Arts SE we want questions that can be answered objectively, so perhaps you can edit your question and ask what would be the pros and cons of practicing both arts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enjoy Kyokushinkai , and you want to learn the close range stuff, my suggestion is that you look at Judo. This is because once you're past the long distance range of karate, you're in the zone where Judo really comes into it's own.

Freestle wrestling would get you tackling/wrestling on the ground in some serious ways, but Judo would really be a better fit to transition / cross-train from Karate.

Comment: Hey Polonski. First of all thank you for the awnser. Highly appreciated. Yes, Judo is the other option, coincidentally there is a great Judo club here also. You make a very strong point. Perhaps I will go with Judo aswell as I have had previous experience with it as a teenager. Yup I'm thinking that will work well with Kyokushin. Thanks heaps. Drew 27 New Zealand

Comment: I'm glad it fell into place for you. Karate > Judo seems like the right match. Once you've mastered those, I'd suggest Bunjinkan Kobudo to complete the journey.